# Google Maps Geocode: Invalid signature for address but not for LatLng

Tags: python, google-maps

Recently I've started having an issue with the Google Maps geocode service using an address.

When sending a LatLng request (below) the request completes successfully, providing the required JSON however when sending an address (using the same signing code and signing proceedure) I receive a `403` with the error message:

> Unable to authenticate the request.
>
> Provided 'signature' is not valid for the provided client ID. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

- `LatLng` - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.092590332%2C-8.78356933594&client=revoked&sensor=true&signature=revoked
- `Address` - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?signature=revoked&client=revoked&sensor=true&address=SW1A+2

I've played around with `http` vs `https`, different types of URL encoding etc but cannot seem to get it to work.

Anybody have any ideas?

For completeness I've included my signing code below:

```
class GoogleGeocoder(Geocoder):

    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

    def build_params(self):
        if self.lon and self.lat:
            self.get_params = {
                'latlng': '{lat},{lon}'.format(
                    lat=self.lat,
                    lon=self.lon
                )
            }
        elif self.address:
            self.get_params = {
                'address': self.address
            }
        else:
            raise Exception("Must provide either an address or (lon, lat)")
        self.get_params['sensor'] = 'true'
        self.get_params['client'] = GOOGLE_CLIENT_STRING

        req = requests.Request('GET', self.url, params=self.get_params)
        r = req.prepare()
        url_for_signing = r.path_url
        decodedKey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(GOOGLE_SIGNING_KEY)
        signature = hmac.new(decodedKey, url_for_signing, hashlib.sha1)
        encodedSignature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest())
        self.get_params['signature'] = encodedSignature
        return self
```